# HighSlide Close

Tags: javascript

I am using Highslide popup. I want to close the popup on button Click. The button is inside the page. For opening  hs.htmlExpand(this, { src: 'add_image.php', objectType: 'iframe' } ) used this function it is opening.

When Closing used this  But it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

use this:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:parent.window.hs.close();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

do this on body tag if you want to close it on clicking outside..

```
<body onClick="hs.close()">
```